# Can application bar items in Windows Phone contain sub items?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I am a beginner in windows phone app development. I just wanted to know whether we can put division of items under one application bar item, for example, if the name of an app bar item is SORT can it contain sub items like SORT BY DATE, SORT BY NAME, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  From [Application Bar Overview for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431813%28v=vs.92%29.aspx#BKMK_Properties)

> The Application Bar menu is not hierarchical and the menu item list is
>   not a submenu of any of the icon buttons.

Comment: But native mail app holds submenu... I guess, it would be nice to store "sort by date", "sort by name" submenus there.